# "string1" + (<condition>)?"string2":"string3"

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements

```
var str1 = "string1" + (false)?"string2":"string3";   // output: string2
var str2 = "string1" + (true)?"string2":"string3";    // output: string2
```

Why do these expressions evaluate to "string2" regardless of true/false in the condition?

What happens to "string1" and "string3" ? How exactly are these expressions being evaluated?

Comment: Read up on operator precedence first before asking a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `?` has less precedence than `+`

```
"string1" + (false)?"string2":"string3"
```

is equivalent to saying:

```
("string1" + false) ? "string2" : "string3"
```

`"string1" + false` evaluates to the string value `"string1false"` which is truthy (Thanks @Vache)

---

To get it to work the way you want, add braces around the ternary expression.

```
"string1" + (false  ? "string2" : "string3")
```

Comment: I'd add that `"string1" + false` produces the string `"string1false"` which is a truthy value.

Comment: @Vache - Good addition. Thank you.